# xpath to select an attribute value where another attribute is a predicate

Tags: javascript, xpath

Say my XML node is this simple:

```
<foo>
    <bar id="1" name="John" />
    <bar id="2" name="Bill">
        <qwert name="Tony" />
    </bar>
</foo>
```

What's the xpath expression to select the name value where I have matched an id already?

`//foo/bar@name` will return the name attributes, but if I want to match an exiting attribute and then return the name, a-la

`//foo/bar[id='1']@name`

throws

> Uncaught Error: INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just

```
//foo/bar[@id='1']/@name
```

Comment: well that's embarrassingly simple, obvious now that I'm looking at it ... I'll just be outside with a box over my head, hiding in shame